# Click events on highcharts with multiple series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When I have multiple series that have intersecting points on my chart the click events don't seem to fire at all.  Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/agnHV/22/

If you take a look at April where all 3 series intersect and try to click on the point it won't do the alert but if you check any of the points that don't intersect they alert properly.

```js
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'°C';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
    
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mm';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                }
    
            }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mb';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            plotOptions:{
                column:{
                    point:{
                        events:{
                            click:function(){
                            alert('aaa');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mm'
                }
    
            }, {
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#AA4643',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mb'
                }
    
            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' °C'
                },
                index: 1,
                zIndex: 99,
                events: {
                 click: function(e) {
                   alert('boom');
                   console.log("CLICKY");
                  }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I've tried adding index/zIndex to give priority to certain points but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Well, the click events seem to be very finicky even outside of the intersection. What are you trying to do / what part of the graph do you want to be clickable?

Comment: @Adjit, it is the Temperature series that has the click event on it so that would be the one he wants to fire even on intersections.

Comment: You actually have 2 events that fire, your 'aaa' alert and 'boom' alert

Comment: Yeah, I put the `aaa` one in there just to prove that its kind of quirky.  The `boom` event is the one I always need clickable.

Comment: Yeah, I mean in general it doesn't seem like the highcharts click event is that reliable. With the `boom` event I've had it where it works on one plot and then I click again and it doesn't work right after...

Comment: Something that may help you out - change `tooltip: shared = true` to `false` and then you can better see what is going on. Also, the click event is more reliable since you see exactly which plot you are clicking on

Comment: You can use [customEvents.js](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin which should fix the issue. Let me know if worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came up with a nice solution for you. Because the individual line events were not reliable I created an event for any point on the graph that was clicked, and then used the event information to pull the name of the series and run a check to see if it is the one that I wanted.

Here is the Javascript that I added: http://jsfiddle.net/agnHV/24/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
        click: function(e){
          var seriesName = e.point.series.name;
          if(seriesName == "Temperature") {
            console.log("Clicked Temperature Line");
          }
          else if(seriesName == "Sea-Level Pressure") {
            console.log("Clicked Sea-Level Line");
          }
          else if(seriesName == "Rainfall") {
            console.log("Clicked Rainfall Bar");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'°C';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
    
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mm';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                }
    
            }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mb';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mm'
                }    
            }, {
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#AA4643',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mb'
                }                    
            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' °C'
                }
                /*events: {
                 click: function(e) {
                   alert('boom');
                   console.log("CLICKY");
                  }
                }*/
            }],
            plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 point: {
                 events: {
                   click: function(e){
                      var seriesName = e.point.series.name;
                      if(seriesName == "Temperature") {
                       console.log("Clicked Temperature Line");
                      }
                      else if(seriesName == "Sea-Level Pressure") {
                       console.log("Clicked Sea-Level Line");
                      }
                      else if(seriesName == "Rainfall") {
                       console.log("Clicked Rainfall Bar");
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }          
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: This is awesome and a great way to get around the issue.  The only thing I'm seeing now is in April the green line ( Temperature ) is on top but the Red line ( Sea ) still has the click triggered on it.

Updated the jsfiddle to show you what I mean (I made the green lineWidth massive http://jsfiddle.net/agnHV/25/ )

Comment: @sontek yeah, I did notice that... not really too sure how you can get around that, aside from making whatever action it is happen for both lines.